# Filtering Discriminated Unions with a Generic Function

Tags: generics, f#, discriminated-union

Given the following union type `MyUnionType`:

```ml
type MyUnionType =
    | TInt of int
    | TString of string
    | TBool of bool
```

...and the following list:

```ml
let myUnionList = [
    TInt 1
    TString "1"
    TInt 3
    TBool false
    TBool false
    TInt 6
    TString "one"
    TString "two"
    TBool true
    TInt 9
]
```

i can filter this list in one awesome go with `List.choose`:

```ml
let filtered =
    myUnionList
    |> List.choose (fun i -> match i with | TString s -> Some s | _ -> None)
```

...where `filtered = [ 1, one, two ]`

Is there any way to make a function that is generic, taking `TString` as an argument or have i run into a limitation of DUs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass `TString` as an argument that is then used in a pattern. However, you can shorten your chooser function so it's closer to what you want:

```ml
List.choose (function TString s -> Some s | _ -> None)
```

This is called ["pattern matching function"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions) syntax.